# incongruent positioning of objects in parallax scrolling site(stellar.js)

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning, parallax

I'm trying to create a simple three 'slide' parallax page using stellar.js (which I have heard has its problems). Ideally, the second two pages contain an image element resting at center-bottom with text floating above it at center-center. At different browser sizes and in different browsers, all of these elements mis-align in different ways.

Here is my mark-up for the last two slides (the first slide is not really a problem):

```
<!--Slide 2-->
<div class="slide" id="slide2" data-slide="2" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <img src="images/slide2/slide2.png" data-stellar-ratio="3" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-20"alt="">
</div>
<span class="slideno"> Here is the layover text. </span>
        <a class="button" data-slide="3" title=""></a>
</div

<!--Slide 3-->
<div class="slide" id="slide3" data-slide="3" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <img src="images/slide3/slide3.png" data-stellar-ratio="1.4" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-20"alt="">
<span class="slideno">Text for slide 3</span>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS for that:

```
/******************************
 SLIDE 2 
*******************************/
#slide2{
    background-color:#f0e9d3;

}
#slide2 img:first-child{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-bottom:-449.5px;
    margin-left:-375px;
    height:899px;
    width:750px;

}
/******************************
 SLIDE 3
*******************************/
#slide3{
    background-color:#d9dddf;
}
#slide3 img:first-child{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-254px;
    margin-left:-506px;
    height:1012px;
    width:508px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your JavaScript code, it looks like there's a couple of issues:

1. Stellar.js can't reposition elements that are positioned using percentages, basically because there's no way to set a value to be '50% + 1px'.
2. You probably need to make sure you only enable scrolling in the direction needed, e.g. `$(window).stellar({ horizontalScrolling: false });`

Hope that helps :)